# trying to netboot Linux using PXELinux 6.03 in a EUFI 64 board, tftp too slow

Tags: linux, pxe-boot, uefi, syslinux

I am trying to set up a kids-school lab, using x5-Z8350 based mini PCs:

https://ark.intel.com/products/93361/Intel-Atom-x5-Z8350-Processor-2M-Cache-up-to-1_92-GHz

Mine seems to have an AMI 64 UEFI "bios". I have managed to offer IP from Ubuntu Server (syslinux 6.03, no need for 6.04 yet) , tftp syslinux.efi,  then ldlinux.e64 later, then vmlinuz image and initrm that takes ages. And then freezes...

I came across:

[Syslinux: How to correctly configure for UEFI PXE boot?](https://serverfault.com/questions/810226/syslinux-how-to-correctly-configure-for-uefi-pxe-boot/810259)

My client declaration also is

PXEClient:Arch:00007:UNDI:003016.

I have 2 problems as of today:

1) InitRM (about 40Mb) is taking like 20 minutes to load, is this due to aforementioned tftp bugs?. I am using atftpd. How can I come around this? vmlinuz and initrm from nfs? other tftp server?

2) Freezing suposedly when loading or executing the kernel. This maybe due to trying to use an i386 image on top of this board...?

Any help or hint very much welcome.

Cheers,
Juan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Definitely the 20 min for a 40 Meg TFTP transfer is the result of Syslinux 6.03 UEFI TFTP bug/s. The only way you have to overcome this is either upgrade Syslinux (even when today 6.04 final does not exist) or transfer by HTTP instead.

2) Arch:00007 implies you have an UEFI 64 client, 
you might have several issues loading UEFI 32 and/or 32 Bit OSs on that architecture.