# What's the equivalence of pxelinux.0 and pxelinux.cfg/default configration for UEFI?

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, tftp, uefi, syslinux

I use Pxe to servers with BIOS(legacy mode), which works perfectly.

Set Legacy mode and boot servers from PXE, it would load pxelinux.0 and read config menus via TFTP from /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default.

Here is `tcpdump` for legacy one

```
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 32: "PXEClient:Arch:00000:UNDI:002001"
            END Option 255, length 0
            PAD Option 0, length 0, occurs 188
18:38:42.626709 00:0c:29:c6:72:77 > Broadcast, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    172.16.234.112.bootps > 255.255.255.255.bootpc: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0x90d61ab8, secs 6, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Your-IP 172.16.235.94
          Server-IP 172.16.234.112
          Client-Ethernet-Address 00:25:90:d6:1a:b8
          file "/pxelinux.0"[|bootp]

18:38:42.628329 00:25:90:d6:1a:b8 > 00:0c:29:c6:72:77, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 70: (tos 0x0, ttl 20, id 3, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)

    172.16.235.94.ah-esp-encap > 172.16.234.112.tftp: [udp sum ok]  28 RRQ "/pxelinux.0" octet tsize 0

    172.16.235.94.49152 > 172.16.234.112.tftp: [udp sum ok]  80 RRQ "/pxelinux.cfg/002590d6-1ab8-0607-0025-90d61ab80e0f" octet tsize 0 blksize 1408
```

We can see DHCP Offered an IP and tftp got `pxelinux.0` and files from `/pxelinux.cfg/`

I can config boot menu on `default`, installing Centos or whatever.

Yet recently I meet the issue that new servers with UEFI.
I know I could be told whether it's legacy or UEFI by `dhcpd.conf`

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 3600;
max-lease-time 3600;
ignore client-updates;
allow booting;
allow bootp;


option client-system-arch code 93 = unsigned integer 16;

class "pxeclients" {

        match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";

        next-server 172.16.234.112;


        if option client-system-arch = 00:00 {


                filename = "/pxelinux.0";

        }

        if option client-system-arch = 00:07 or option client-system-arch = 00:09{

                filename = "/BOOTX64.EFI";

        }

}

subnet 172.16.232.0 netmask 255.255.248.0 {

        option routers                  172.17.232.1;
        option subnet-mask              255.255.248.0;
        option domain-name-servers      202.106.0.20;
        range dynamic-bootp 172.16.235.2 172.16.239.253;

}
```

BOOTX64.EFI is from Centos7.5 ISO.

It's all right when it's Legacy, but it hangs on

```
start PXE Over IPV4
```

The screen flashes and switches from another windows(Cannot see what's it, incredibly fast).

Seeing from `messages`, it kept DHCP Request and offer.

```
Mar  8 19:32:36 ks dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 172.16.235.95 (172.16.234.112) from 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:36 ks dhcpd: DHCPACK on 172.16.235.95 to 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:36 ks dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:36 ks dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 172.16.235.95 to 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:40 ks dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 172.16.235.95 (172.16.234.112) from 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:40 ks dhcpd: DHCPACK on 172.16.235.95 to 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:40 ks dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:40 ks dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 172.16.235.95 to 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:44 ks dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 172.16.235.95 (172.16.234.112) from 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:44 ks dhcpd: DHCPACK on 172.16.235.95 to 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:44 ks dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192
Mar  8 19:32:44 ks dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 172.16.235.95 to 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34 via ens192

......
```

Here is tcpdump from DHCP servers `port 67`.

```
   0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34, length 359, xid 0xe8ffad6f, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Client-Ethernet-Address 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34
          Vendor-rfc1048 Extensions
            Magic Cookie 0x63825363
            DHCP-Message Option 53, length 1: Request
            Server-ID Option 54, length 4: 172.16.234.112
            Requested-IP Option 50, length 4: 172.16.235.95

     ......

            GUID Option 97, length 17: 0.55.53.53.50.53.56.54.67.85.53.52.49.88.52.75.88
            NDI Option 94, length 3: 1.3.16
            ARCH Option 93, length 2: 7
            Vendor-Class Option 60, length 32: "PXEClient:Arch:00007:UNDI:003016"
            END Option 255, length 0

19:32:28.031210 00:0c:29:c6:72:77 > Broadcast, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 342: (tos 0x10, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 328)
    172.16.234.112.bootps > 255.255.255.255.bootpc: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 300, xid 0xe8ffad6f, Flags [Broadcast] (0x8000)
          Your-IP 172.16.235.95
          Server-IP 172.16.234.112
          Client-Ethernet-Address 5c:b9:01:92:f6:34
          file "BOOTX64.EFI"[|bootp]
```

It seems server offered `BOOTX64.EFI` but client did not accept as tcpdump 'port 69` returned nothing.

In legacy mode, tcpdump port 69, files are downloaded by client.

Seeing from above message, Server's identity is

```
PXEClient:Arch:00007:UNDI:003016
```

which should match `else` and load `BOOTX64.EFI`

So I'm pretty confused, what's wrong?

What's the equivalent of UEFI config, it should match client (To detect it's UEFI or Legacy) and there should be a file which is the same as `pxelinux.0` as bootloader, and a file to read boot menus.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

I googled all day, nothing useful was found, including Redhat Docs.

Explore1, seeing from this [page](https://serverfault.com/questions/810226/syslinux-how-to-correctly-configure-for-uefi-pxe-boot), it said `syslinux.efi` is the one which same as `pxelinux.0`, I change `dhcpd.conf` and restart, does not work ,either.

Comment: EDIT-1:  Redhat Docs is for RHEL6, which seems correct. But it does not apply to Centos7.X.

Comment: EDIT2: I'm sucessfully caputed the error log,

NBP filename is xxx.efi
NBP filesize is 0 Bytes.
PXE-E99 error, unexpected network error.
---
Turns out I misconfigured the router of dhcpd.conf.
--
And `BOOTX64.EFI`(for SecureBoot) and `grubx64.efi` are both usable from Centos ISO file.
And syslinux-6.03 is usable, too.
Thanks everyone.
problems solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- pxelinux.0 offers you a PXE menu for booting legacy targets
- BOOTX64.EFI will help you to boot a particular Linux distro but you won't have a menu of different PXE booting assets
- <s>**pxelinux.efi**</s> **syslinux.efi** offers you a PXE menu for booting **UEFI** targets

Comment: `pxelinux.efi`? never heard of it. Could you show me any links about this?

Comment: you are right; sorry my typo...

Answer (score 0):

The sad thing is that I type a wrong ip address
`option routers                  172.17.232.1;`
should be 172.16 not 172.17

Thanks everyone.